How to use --exec option in nestjs command
I'm trying to use the --exec option to run a command before the nestjs server start (--require).
I want to modify the start:dev script in my package.json
But I can not make it work, always got an error
this command line works fine :
npx ts-node --require ./src/common/telemetry/telemetry.ts ./src/main.ts

I tried these couple of syntax in package.json
 "start:dev": "nest start --watch --exec  \"ts-node --require ./src/common/telemetry/telemetry.ts\"",

 "start:dev": "nest start --watch --exec  ts-node --require ./src/common/telemetry/telemetry.ts",

but both failed with ARG_UNKOWN_OPTION error (see details below).
Thks for your help
Error: Unknown or unexpected option: --enable-source-maps
    at arg (C:\Users\jerom\dev\stelogy\apiLeoniJira\node_modules\arg\index.js:88:19)
    at parseArgv (C:\Users\jerom\dev\stelogy\apiLeoniJira\node_modules\ts-node\dist\bin.js:69:12)
    at main (C:\Users\jerom\dev\stelogy\apiLeoniJira\node_modules\ts-node\dist\bin.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jerom\dev\stelogy\apiLeoniJira\node_modules\ts-node\dist\bin.js:579:5)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1546:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1691:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1317:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1127:12)
    at TracingChannel.traceSync (node:diagnostics_channel:315:14)
    at wrapModuleLoad (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:217:24) {
  code: 'ARG_UNKNOWN_OPTION'
}


which nodejs version are you using?

@MicaelLevi V22.9

that --enable-source-maps flag is injected by NestJS's CLI for NodeJS. As you're using ts-node instead of node, it won't work because ts-node does not support --enable-source-maps (see https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/807)
As per https://github.com/nestjs/nest-cli/issues/2678#issuecomment-2268336322 you can probably use ts-node alone instead of via NestJS's CLI.

got it, will go this way
